# regex replace html tag with all attributes inside on special character

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex skills aren't so high so I apologize in advance if my question will bother somebody.

I'm trying to convert string in two ways

1. From special character => html tag with attributes
2. Form html tag with attributes => special character

the first way works fine and looks next:

```
var string = "User template user info: {{userFirstname}} - {{userLastname}}";
var text = string
            .replace(/\{{/g, "<span class='label label-danger' contenteditable='false' style='padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;'>")
            .replace(/\}}/g, "<span contenteditable='false' class='remove-tag fa fa-times'></span></span>&nbsp;");
```

the second way doesn't work and I can't understand the reason:

```
var text = 'User template user info: <span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">userFirstname<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"></span></span>&nbsp; - <span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">userLastname<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"></span></span>&nbsp;
var string = text
            .replace(/<span class='label label-danger' contenteditable='false' style='padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;'>/g, "{{")
            .replace(/<span contenteditable='false' class='remove-tag fa fa-times'><\/span><\/span>&nbsp;/g, "}}")
```

I appreciate if anybody could tell me what I'm missing. Thanks in advance

Comment: The replace value has its attribute values wrapped in single quotes `contenteditable='false'`, while the `text` property value has its attribute values wrapped in double quotes `contenteditable="false"`. This causes the replace to not find the specified string due to mismatching quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While simple replace based upon placeholder often work, replacing complex HTML-elements are easy to fail with regex.

I would recommend another approach here!

The top approach gives you control over which elements you want to eliminate and which to preserve. The bottom approach strips all HTML and assumes you know the content of the `span`.

```js
var text = 'User template user info: <span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">userFirstname<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"></span></span>&nbsp; - <span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">userLastname<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"></span></span>&nbsp;'

function replaceSpan(text)
{
  //convert text into virtual DOM object
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", text);
  //loop over children and replace
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(div.querySelectorAll("span"), function(element){
  
    if (element.contentEditable == "false" && element.classList.contains("label") && element.classList.contains("label-danger") )
    {
      elementContent = element.textContent;
      element.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode("{{"+elementContent+"}}"), element);
      
    }
  });
  console.log(div.textContent);
  return div.textContent
}

replaceSpan(text);
```

Also this could be simplified:

```js
var text = 'User template user info: <span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">userFirstname<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"></span></span>&nbsp; - <span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">userLastname<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"></span></span>&nbsp;'

var string = document.createElement("div");
string.innerHTML = text;
// use textContent of div element to return text without HTML
string =  string.textContent.replace("userFirstname", "{{userFirstname}}")
          .replace("userLastname", "{{userLastname}}");
          
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer, I can't use the second way because some of the content is dynamic, but the first way is absolutely amazing! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The replace value has its attribute values wrapped in single quotes `contenteditable='false'`, while the `text` property value has its attribute values wrapped in double quotes `contenteditable="false"`. This causes the replace to not find the specified string due to mismatching quotes.

The `text` variable is also missing a closing `'`

```
// replace now searching with " instead of '
var text = 'User template user info: <span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">userFirstname<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"></span></span>&nbsp; - <span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">userLastname<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"></span></span>&nbsp;'
var string = text
        .replace(/<span class="label label-danger" contenteditable="false" style="padding: 6px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px;">/g, "{{")
        .replace(/<span contenteditable="false" class="remove-tag fa fa-times"><\/span><\/span>&nbsp;/g, "}}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is some sort of workaround, but it works for me

```
 var string = text
            .replace(/<span[^>]*>/g, "{{")
            .replace(/<\/span[^>]*>/g, "")
            .replace(/{{&nbsp;/g, "}}");
```